# Android application that doesn't run

Tags: android

I made a simple application that adds 1 to the count and displays the count on a TextView. It compiled and installed fine, but when I run it, a message immediately says "Unfortunately, Counter has stopped."

```
package com.android.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CounterActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private static int count = 0;
Button increment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inc);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CountDisp);


Runnable update = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() {
        increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                count++;
                tv.setText("Count:" + count);
            }
        });
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Thread thr = new Thread(update);
    thr.start();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content of the `Activity` BEFORE trying to find any of the views. Doing this...

```
Button increment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inc);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CountDisp);
```

...where you currently are, will mean both `increment` and `tv` will be `null`. Change those lines to...

```
Button increment;
TextView tv';
```

Then use `findViewById(...)` in `onCreate(...)` AFTER you have called `setContentView(...)`

Also, using a separate `Thread` (Runnable) to handle the `onClick(...)` listener is over complicating things and isn't necessary. Simply create your `onClick(...)` listener within `onCreate(...)` and forget about the other thread code.

Comment: actually `tv.setText(...)` will not fail since it will be called on UI thread ... the only part not called on UI thread is `increment.setOnClickListener`

Comment: @Selvin: Good point and I've edited my answer. My brain's slowing down - I think I need another coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in LogCat. You can do it with Eclipse, or the DDMS tool. The LogCat log will show you:

- What the exception was
- Where in the code it occurred

Using that information you can then find the cause. Doing it from the source code alone is just masochism.